# Check if cluster parameter group exists , if not then only create using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

**Requirement** - I want to create a cluster parameter group by checking first , if it already exists (which might not be created by terraform), then don't run the create resource block . If not then only create it.

**1st issue** - I couldn't find data source to fetch existing cluster parameter group. Kindly help me with that.

**2nd** - If there is any better way to achieve this or are there any other issue , which can occur in below code.

```
module "pg" {
  count                               = 2
  source                              = "./module/pg"
  cluster_parameter_group             = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].cluster_parameter_group
  cluster_parameter_group_family      = var.aurora_mysql[count.index].cluster_parameter_group_family
}
```

**Input variables**
Here I am giving same input variables so that for aurora_mysql[0] it will create it , but for aurora_mysql[1] is should not attempt to create resource.

```
aurora_mysql = [
    {
                cluster_parameter_group          = "aurora-mysql-cluster-parameter-group"     
                cluster_parameter_group_family   = "aurora-mysql5.7"
    },
    {
                cluster_parameter_group          = "aurora-mysql-cluster-parameter-group"     
                cluster_parameter_group_family   = "aurora-mysql5.7"
    }
]
```

**Module**

```
data "block to fetch existing parameter group" {
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "pg" {
  count                               = data.aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.cpg.id != "" ? 1 : 0
  name                                = var.cluster_parameter_group
  family                              = var.cluster_parameter_group_family
  description                         = "rds aurora mysql paramter group"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if it already exists

Terraform (TF) does not have any build in tools for checking if something exists or not. This is **against principles** of how TF works. The core principle of TF is that if a resource is not-managed by TF, it does not exist. Similarly in terms of data sources, they must already exist, as there is no middle-ground that it may or may not exist.

Having said that there are ways to hack-up a solution to your requirement. Namely you can create your own [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). Since this is your custom data source you can design it to check if for existence of resources and return true/false to TF for further use.

Comment: I've also seen this issue addressed by wrapping Terraform in a script that conditionally imports resources that are evaluated as already existing before forming a plan.